# Is there an R function to combine two variables into one before dummying?

Tags: r, variables

I've got a problem with creating dummy variables out of a dataset that contains information about housing. In this case the type of house (Appartment, Villa, Farmhouse, home, Home, Penthouse).

As you can see home and Home are the same variable. That's why I would like to combine them into one variable before creating dummy variables.

```
var1 <- house$housetype$Home
var2 <- house$housetype$home
```

My expected output contains one variable (house$housetype$home), that counts for the houses of var1 als well as var2.

Does anyone of you know a good function I could use for this?

Comment: How about `paste`?

Comment: Assuming there are no duplicates you could do: `var <- c(house$housetype$Home, house$housetype$home)` to concatenate the two variables.

Comment: Or use `lowercase` on the respective variable before creating dummies.